# Perform Django model operation after a response has been sent with Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have created a very simple setup with articles and comments, in which users can post comments to articles through an api created with the Django Rest framework.

So far so good. The problem is I have several expensive operations that need to be performed when a comment is created (such as sending email notifications), but I would like for them to be performed AFTER the response has returned, so the user won't have to wait.

```
class Comment(CommentBase):
article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #Expensive operations here, which should run after a response has been returned.
    super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

As far as I know, the rest framework won't send a response until after a model-save has been performed.

How do I best run operations after the response has been returned? Can I use post-signal, or is this something I need to do with Celery?

Comment: This is exactly what celery is for.

Comment: even django background tasks is simple alternative

Comment: Thanks! I was unsure since this was the first time, I had to do something like this. I will look into using Celery or Django background tasks.

Comment: If you want lightweight and easy to integrate solution for doing background jobs, you can try `Django-Q` https://django-q.readthedocs.io/en/latest/